# Windows service not able to hit network drive path asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-services

I have one windows service which used to place files on network drive. It is working fine on some machines but on some machines it is not working fine. Although when i am trying to do with Window application it is working fine.

Please suggest me how i can solve this issue. As there are more than 100 of systems where this service installed but I am getting this issue random basis.
[image]

Comment: Are all instances of your service running under the same account?

Comment: If they are not all the same accout, then check to see if all the accounts have permissions to the destination network folder

Comment: Yes, on local system account. added snapshot. Could you provide me robust way so that it can be handled by config file etc.

Comment: @Sean Installer using local system account during setup.

Comment: what permissions do you have on share folder (drive) ? Is it allowed for everyone (anonymous) access? Do you have any error in the service log? How do you access the shared folder - by network path or mapped drive?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable comments.

I found one more thing and this is definitely missing from Networking team. They had provided the access only on child folder not on the root folder that's why service was not able to hit mapped directory.

After provide the full permission to root directory, service is able to place files.

All possible scenarios which provided in comments will also be helpful for me to solve issues related with same domain.